# Apple UI Guidelines, tabs bars and toolbars

Tags: gui-design, ios, mobile-application, human-interface-guideline, apple

I want to publish my app to the Apple App Store. I created the app in PhoneGap.

It's a learn a new language app, with different sections.
In the Android version, I have tab bars at the top. These tab bars relate to the content of that specific page. 
 Example: Chapter 1 section Alex, we learn about colors. In Chapter 1 section Cecilie, we can learn about verbs.

I have attached an image.
[image]

My question:
Do I need to move the tabs to the bottom of the page. 
The tabs are not the same for the whole app. They change depending on the Person (Alex, Ben) and Chapter selected.

Comment: Just a quick comment, I believe it is spelled Grammar.

Answer (score 2):

No. Use a segmented control for the iOS version instead of a tab bar and keep it in the header below the Chapter label.